# How to get Identity Providers Name

Tags: c#, azure, acs

I am using azure Access Control Service (ACS). I am trying to get the list of Identity providers which i was selected for my application. For this i am using the following code [From Here](http://blogs.southworks.net/mwoloski/2011/04/12/adding-internet-identity-providers-like-facebook-google-liveid-and-yahoo-to-your-mvc-web-application-using-windows-azure-appfabric-access-control-service-and-jquery-in-3-steps/):

```
public ActionResult IdentityProviders(string serviceNamespace, string appId)
{
    string idpsJsonEndpoint = string.Format(IdentityProviderJsonEndpoint, serviceNamespace, appId);
    var client = new WebClient();
    var data = client.DownloadData(idpsJsonEndpoint);

    return Content(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data), "application/json");
}
```

Can anybody please tell me what is appId and where do i get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the link you provided you need to get that from here.

https://portal.appfabriclabs.com

Also check for the below line in the link

```
{ serviceNamespace = "YourServiceNamespace", appId = "https://localhost/<YourWebApp>/" }))',
```

The `appId` will be the one you will get after registration

[image]